# Is it ethical to apply job now although the requirement said "fresh graduate"?

Tags: job-search, careers, indonesia

Now I am in 7th semester in computer science faculty and currently working on my thesis and being an intern at company XYZ

After graduating, I want to immediately work full time.

If my company does not offer me a full time job, then I'd need to apply before I am graduated, so I can start to search for full time jobs as programmer or software developer or data analyst.

I see all the requirements said fresh graduate, but I haven't graduate and I want to apply, is it ethical? or am I likely to get rejected if I apply before graduating.

Comment: How long before you are graduated? 6 months? 11 months?

Comment: @SouravGhosh expected month is april i already graduated

Comment: Does not matter how long before you are graduated. It's never unethical to apply for a job. You are being too careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the worst that can happen if you apply now?

They may reject you. But I don't think that any company will then ban you from future application. They are more likely to see your keenness in a positive light.

How long until you graduate?

Personally, I would probably interview you. I like to  plan projects in advance, and knowing that I have you planned for a slot 6 months from now (or whenever) is one less thing that I have to worry about.

Saying that they are looking for a new graduate is way of indicating the salary range and the nature of the duties. Personally, I would take someone with 1 or even 2 years experience in a new grad position, if he were happy with the salary & job description. Especially, if they had had the poor luck to land a bad first job, so were effectively still at new grad level.

Tl;dr - I don't see how it could hurt, it will probably look positive and the worst that is likely to happen is that you are invited to reapply closer to your graduation date.

Comment: How long until you graduate? -> my thesis will done in february3(deadline) and will get the defense maybe in march so april i already graduate

Comment: Then you can certainly start applying now. That is well within a normal recruitment time-frame.  In fact, if you are in the UK it would be optimal, because that's when their tax year starts , so that's when projects get their new year's budgets. But, wherever you are, by all means start applying now. I am surprised, though, that your university has not offered advice.

Comment: hehe perhaps im doing intern in company (which this internship is a program from my university) maybe they only concern about the internship and the thesis that the student did now .. But i got advice from my coworker here to start look for a job  (if my company didnt offered me the full time job)

Comment: That is certainly the easiest way to get your first job. If you enjoy working at the company where you are interning, then ask if there is an opening for you. That's a major part of having interns (outer than free labo(u)r) - an internship is a long interview. They should know buy know if you are a good fit, and , if you are, they would rather have you than someone whom they interview for a few hours at most. Apply to both, and good luck :-)

Comment: this is the problem ,  they already offered me to join the IT Program in this company (basically like i need to train for 6.5 months and then if i pass the test , i will become a full time employee) .. but its not like software company that they will give you contract and then sign immediately, i need to pass online , offline test and now im already at HR interview .. now its already 1 month but i havent get any update about the interview result .. thats why im concern to look for a job now hehe (I work at finance industry for IT Division)

Comment: Then pursue both - and more, more, more - and see accept the first offer which you like.

Comment: okay i will try your advice , thankyou so much

Comment: Please let us know how it works out. If you tell us here, it might help others in future

Comment: sure , i will update the result when it has progress

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with ethics. Apply for any job you wish. Clearly state your current situation and if HR is as super smart as people on workplace think they are, they will figure it out.

Comment: "` if HR is as super smart as people on workplace think they are`" - citation needed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it ethical to apply job now although the requirement said “fresh graduate”?*

Yes, you can apply.

To add, this is more about whether it is *practical*, rather than *ethical*. As you mentioned, you are supposed to finish your graduation in ~3 months, you **should** start applying for positions **now onward**.

Basically you have two options to land at a full-time job as of now:

- **Either the organization where you're an intern offers you a permanent / full-time position:** The current organization might offer you a position after your graduation is complete, however, it's not certain whether they're going to extend an offer until you receive it and even if you get the offer, the compensation might not be a fit for you.
- **Or, you look for other opportunities elsewhere:** You can start exploring other opportunities for fresh graduates and attend interviews for various positions that suits your skills.

As we can see, exploring options at this point is the best course of action for you. The interview and hiring process takes some times, and you may want to be interviewed for more than one opportunities - so, you can start applying now, go through the process and by the time you are graduated, you'll have the start date in close proximity.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, apply for this job.**  When they specify "fresh graduate" in the help-wanted posting, it often means they want people like you to apply.

Near the top of your resume and in your cover letter, be sure to write "I expect to receive my Bachelor of Science degree (or whatever) from the University of California (or whereever) in June 2020 (or whenever).  Hiring managers and recruiters know exactly what this means.

And some of them get incentives for recruiting people like you immediately on graduation.

(I've been on university recruiting teams. Hiring new grads is a big deal in some companies.)